# Sculpting Lag and Freezing

Tags: add-on, sculpting

I recently saw the sculpt January and decided to try out sculpting in blender, which I usually use for hard surface modelling with subsurfs. I saw people using Dyntopo, so i enabled it but whenever I get to a level of detail like 100000 polys the viewport lags hard. My cursor still moves, but the red circle freezes as it tries to follow it, making a slideshow, and so it draws just straight lines. Another way I can get this issue is with using a resolution of 50 constant detail with dyntopo on the basic 2x2x2 cube. It lags whenever I try to draw on it.

I'm on blender 2.79 with no addons installed. My P specs are b85-g41 PC Mate Mobo Intel i5 4460 3,2 Ghz CPU Nvidia Geforce GTX 970 3GB With 16 Gb of corsair RAM.

I have a WACOM bamboo tablet drivers, but am just testing with the mouse. I did use the tablet but it had the same problem.

I've reinstalled blender, tried older versions and tried it in steam. All to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Blender sculpting is not very well optimized. Even on high-end hardware the brushes will lag, undo will lag on multi-million poly meshes. It is to be expected. It should be usable though. If you are experiencing lag on polycounts lower than 1M, something is bad with your setup. Your HW should be enough for sculpting around 1M polys.

Comment: In addition to Glen Larsen's answer below you should also double-check if you switched OpenSubdiv Compute to GLSL under "User Preferences" - "System".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answers to [question 3516](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3516/how-can-i-improve-viewport-performance-when-using-dyntopo)

Dyntopo is increasing the density of the mesh for you as you sculpt and it is very demanding on performance at that resolution. To see this:

1. In Properties panel -> Object -> Display, enable Wire and Draw All
   Edges.
2. Repeat your test of resolution 50 at constant detail on a default cube with dyntopo enabled

If you need to sculpt at this level of detail, you will have to upgrade some hardware.

Tablet vs. mouse is not relevant.

Comment: When you are recommending investing into HW, it is also good to recommend investing into better software, like Zbrush. The Zbrush Core version is much cheaper than any HW upgrade significant to OP's current specs and will enable him sculpting 10M+ meshes.

Comment: @Jerryno - the hardware should be completely fine for sculpting in Blender. I sculpted quite some nice details on way crappier machines since Dyntopo was added in 2.66

Comment: @metaphor_set yep, I commented this to the OP directly under the question, as that seemed the better place. You are right. This comment was directed to promote that SW upgrades shouldn't be overlooked when speaking about spending money to make Blender perform better.